# Capture image with dual lens without calling camera application using HTC One M8

Tags: android, android-camera

Recently I have been trying to develop an app that capture a image without having to call the camera application by using camera2 sample from github https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.

But the picture taken from camera2 sample cannot visualize captured depth information using HTC dual lens demo 
https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-dual-lens-api/sdk-overview-sample-code/ (as I suspect that the picture is not taken with duo lens).

Is it possible to take photo with duo lens by modifying camera2 sample? And it is possible to capture image with dual lens without calling camera application using HTC One M8?